# Microsoft DOS vs Unix

Tags: unix, dos

Which one is more powerful operating system? And is it possible to convert Microsoft-DOS batch file into Unix Script and vice-versa?

Comment: You're kidding, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOS is a 16-bit monouser operating system, without any kind of memory protection. UNIX is a 32/64 bit multiuser operating system, with multiprocess scheduling, userspace/kernel space separation and memory protection.

From just that description, i can say UNIX is a lot more powerful than DOS. But of course depends on your requirements :)

Is it possible to convert a .bat file to a unixshell script, sure, just do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you define power. By most common definitions a multi-user OS (UNIX) is more powerful than a single user one (DOS). However this is not always the case. If your requirements are for a embedded single user system , then one could argue that a single user OS is better.